# Action properties

Tags: c#, action

Can anybody explain me this code extract.

```
public abstract Action<int> serialpacket { set; get; }
```

I am a bit confused about it. I know roughly what it does but it would be better if somebody can shed a bit light on it.

Comment: There are *lots* of different concepts here. We don't know which bit is confusing you. Do you understand delegates? Automatically implemented properties? Abstract members? Generics?

Comment: Well... [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) [Action<int>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) [serialpacket { set; get; }](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serialpacket` is an abstract property that, when implemented, will return a method reference or lamda that takes an integer parameter and returns nothing.

e.g (ignoring the setter).

```
public override Action<int> serialpacket
{
    get { return i => Console.WriteLine(i); }
    set { ... }
}
```

or

```
public void Trousers(int i)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}

public Action<int> serialpacket
{
    get { return Trousers; }
    set { ... }
}
```

One could then use serialpacket thusly:

```
serialpacket(10);
```

As it is a property with a setter, one could also do:

```
public override Action<int> serialpacket { get; set; }

serialpacket = Trousers;
serialpacket(10);
// prints 10 to the console
```

With the same definition of `Trousers` as above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what do you mean by **will return a method reference or lamda that takes an integer parameter and returns nothing.**

Comment: Well one thing. In `public Action<int> serialpacket
{
    get { return Trousers; }
}` you didnt implemeted the `set`. whats the reson for it

Answer (score 0):

> Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return
>   a value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

EDIT: In your example, it is a property to which you can assign (in a derived class - because it is `abstract`) a delegate that takes an `int` and does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a property of type `Action<int>`. `Action<int>` is a function that takes `int` parameter and doesn't return a value.

You can use it as follows:

```
instance.serialpacket(42);
```

The property is `abstract` - it must be overridden in a concrete derived class.

It is a bit bizarre to have an `abstract` property with a public setter. What would probably be better is a read-only property:

```
public abstract Action<int> serialpacket { get; }
```

Otherwise, if the property can be set publicly, than a non-abstract version will be enough

```
public Action<int> serialpacket { get; set; }
```

You can also limit the setter to derived classes:

```
public Action<int> serialpacket { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: Wrong. Takes an `int` parameter and return no value.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Updated an answer.